# How to create a discord bot that streams online radio in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

As mentioned in the title, how do I do it? So far I spent a couple of hours trying to find an answer but since this isn't a popular request there isn't anything about it. Most of what I found is just using youtube-dl for downloading yt audio and playing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit/Update to use [FFmpegPCMAudio](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.FFmpegPCMAudio) to stream.

You'll also need to workout your streaming url for your desired channel. [Radio Paradise](https://radioparadise.com/listen/stream-links) provides some links and I'm sure there are many others.

You can try the following to get you rolling, of course the member entering the commands needs to be in the voice channel:

```py
import os

from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
PREFIX = os.getenv('DISCORD_PREFIX')

client = Bot(command_prefix=list(PREFIX))


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Music Bot Ready')


@client.command(aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = 'http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    global player
    try:
        player = await channel.connect()
    except:
        pass
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('http://stream.radioparadise.com/rock-128'))


@client.command(aliases=['s', 'sto'])
async def stop(ctx):
    player.stop()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Also for the people that get the issue "Could not find module 'libvlc.dll'" use 
 ```os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\your\VLC\directory')```. For me this doesn't solve the issue if the 64bit version of vlc is installed.

Comment: It does stream audio but not from the bot in the voice channel, rather from PyCharm itself. So only I can hear the actual radio.

Comment: @Pudge - thought I verified that it played through the voice channel. Updated to use FFmpegPCMAudio to stream and verified on external hosting to avoid the pycharm issue.

Comment: It works flawlessly now. Thank you for replying back!

PS: At first it threw an error when I attempted to import FFmpegPCMaudio and I thought I had some library issues, but it turns out I had to list it as the final import for it to work. Amateur mistakes, but I digress. Just another heads up for people that may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this](https://pypi.org/project/radiopy/) be of any use? Potentially use [this example](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107433/discord.FFmpegPCMAudio) as a skeleton for your bot. Not needing to use any YT-DL - proves that you can use local mp3 files.