# . Why does it give me a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object" error? Code's in python

Tags: python, audio, discord, discord.py, bots

```
import os

from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('OTY2MDQ5MjA1ODg4MDk0MjY4.Yl8Fbw.k3ftJGOLznBIFmdnaFCNd73qaEk')
PREFIX = os.getenv('!')

client = Bot(command_prefix = list(PREFIX)) 


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Nichijou Shuffle Bot Ready')


@client.command(aliases=['p', 'play'])
async def play(ctx, url: str = 'https://node-33.zeno.fm/tncreqmcwnhvv?zs=tdK49JAMSyu6lo3su_Wf-A&rj-tok=AAABgEq0dCAA2dBg3bs1EtEs7Q&rj-ttl'):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    global player
    try:
        player = await channel.connect()
    except:
        pass
    player.play(FFmpegPCMAudio('https://node-33.zeno.fm/tncreqmcwnhvv?zs=tdK49JAMSyu6lo3su_Wf-A&rj-tok=AAABgEq0dCAA2dBg3bs1EtEs7Q&rj-ttl'))


@client.command(aliases=['s', 'stop'])
async def stop(ctx):
    player.stop()


client.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm trying out this discord bot that plays music through a stream link. The error is happening in line 11. Credit to [davestsomewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1935238/davestsomewhere) for the code. I didn't modify the code at all but it keeps showing me the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error. Don't know how to code but I think this is the only place where I can get an answer.

Comment: Remove your token.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the `PREFIX` that is equal to `None`. Thus the problem lies at the initialization of the `PREFIX`.

`os.gentenv()` returns the value of the environment variable key if it exists otherwise returns the default value. I don't know what you are trying to achieve with `os.getenv('!')`, but either the value associated with this key is `None`, either the key doesn't exist and the default value is in your case set to `None`.

Comment: In davestsomewhere's post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763028/16624114, they said I need to put my discord prefix there so I put '!'. What am I suppose to put there?

Comment: I'd have taken the post literally if I were you, try with `DISCORD_TOKEN` and `DISCORD_PREFIX`?

Comment: That doesnt fix it

Comment: I have no idea then, you might want to dive deeper in the script/documentation, and ask for more explanation from the creator.

Answer (score 0):

the issue can be replicated in this minimal example:

```py
import os
PREFIX = os.getenv('!')
list(PREFIX)
```

The environment variable `!` is not set, PREFIX then is `None` and making a list out of it is not possible. I'm not sure what should be in the environment variable and `!` seems like a uncommon name to me.

Comment: So what exactly should i do to fix it?